# speed up my function about build bill of materials with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datatable

for me a Python fresh, I m working on a code for building bill of materials(BOM), which can get the customer's desired item id and purchase quantity from the order sheet in the excel file and use another BOM sheet(also in the same excel) to calculate the quantity of all raw materials needed.After subtracting the stock of raw materials from the inventory, the remaining demand is input to the dictionary output like{id_material: quantity}.
The format of BOM sheet as follow

| item_id  |process_id |process_No.|  IN/OUT  |material_id |quantity_in |quantity_out |
| -------- | --------  | --------  | -------- | --------   | --------   | --------    |
|    A     |   z420    |     1     |   IN     |   12125    |    100     |     Nan     |
|    A     |   z420    |     1     |   OUT    |  A-z512-2  |    Nan     |     100     |
|    A     |   z512    |     2     |   IN     |  A-z512-2  |    100     |     Nan     |
|    A     |   z512    |     2     |   OUT    |  A-z600-3  |    Nan     |     120     |
|    A     |   z600    |     3     |   IN     |  A-z600-3  |    120     |     Nan     |
|    A     |   z600    |     3     |   OUT    |   14551    |    Nan     |     -20     |
|    A     |   z600    |     3     |   OUT    |     A      |    Nan     |     100     |
attr: processs_id : Process id used

attr: processs_No.: Process order in the process path. Not always consecutive or regular like natural                          numbers, such as (51, 60, 70, 100)

attr:   IN/OUT    : Indicate whether the material is a raw material or an output

the pandas.dataframe I use is also like this but two attr columns added: 'count_demand' for indicate the quantity needed and 'flag'  for my function to identify the material that needs to be executed.Lets call it 'df_demand'.

I was able to complete the functions that would serve my purpose, but the speed was not satisfactory. I tested with moudles such as timeit and found some operations that took a lot of time, but I couldn't think of a way to optimize them, so I came here for help.

1. The first thing I found unsatisfactory and the most time-consuming part of the whole process was a function that was used by my code to find the raw material of the current demand material and to calculate the demand quantity of the raw material in proportion to the BOM according to the quantity of the demand material.The code as follow

```
def calculate_demand_raw(row, df_demand):
    try:
       if np.isnan(row['quantity_out']):
           raise ValueError('To avoid including those recycled materials with negative outputs')

       list_index = list(df_demand['item_id'].isin([row['item_id']]) &
                         df_demand['process_No.'].isin([row['process_No.']]) &
                         df_demand['IN/OUT'].isin(['IN']))
       index = [i for i, x in enumerate(list_index) if x==True]  
       # Search to find the index of the required generation process

       df_demand.loc[index, 'count_demand'] = row['count_demand']/row['quantity_out']*
                                               df_demand.loc[index, 'quantity_in']
       # calculate quantity of raw materials.
       df_demand.loc[index, 'flag'] = 1

    except ValueError:
        pass  # Prevent the query material is the base material, no process generation
    df_demand.loc[row.name, 'flag'] = 0

df_demand[df_demand['flag'].isin([1])].apply(lambda row: calculate_demand_raw(row, df_demand), axis=1)
```

timeit told me that, in the function, it takes three times as long to find the index of the eligible rows as it does to calculate the quantity of the raw material, and calculate_demand_raw is also the  most time-consuming function in a loop.So could anyone have a deal of search index time reduction?

2. The second time-consuming function in a loop is a function that fill the aggregated raw material requirements into the df_demand's attr'count_demand' where they are generated for the process.

```
def fill_demand(row, qty_sum_demand, df_demand):
    df_demand[row.name, 'count_demand'] += qty_sum_demand.loc[
                                qty_sum_demand['IN/OUT'].isin([row['IN/OUT']).tolist(),
                                'count_demand'].tolist()
    df_demand.loc[index, 'flag'] = 1

df_demand.loc[index_generated_process].apply(lambda row: 
                                fill_demand(row, qty_sum_demand, df_demand), axis=1)
```

Is it the conditional search in the function that makes it take so long, just like calculate_demand_raw? Is it possible to turn this operation into a faster numpy vectorization operation?

Thx a lot for any help and suggestions

Comment: I can't help (I would just suggest putting into a relational database), but out of interest how many records are in your raw materials table?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, about 29800 rows from df_bom and 329 orders from df_orders. and it takes about 50s to finish calculation

Comment: I delete the loop code in func calculate_demand_raw and use 'list_index' instead of 'index' as row index in .loc(), makes running twice as fast. But still struggled in conditional search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A modified version of your example to show some functionality:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(
"""
item_id,process_id,process_No.,IN/OUT,material_id,quantity_in,quantity_out,flag
A,z420,1,IN,12125,100.0,,0
A,z420,1,OUT,A-z512-2,,100.0,0
A,z512,2,IN,A-z512-2,100.0,,0
A,z512,2,OUT,A-z600-3,,120.0,0
A,z600,3,IN,A-z600-2,,400,1
A,z600,3,IN,A-z600-3,120.0,200,1
A,z600,3,IN,14551,,-20.0,0
A,z600,3,OUT,A,,100.0,0
""".strip()
))
```

```
  item_id process_id  process_No. IN/OUT material_id  quantity_in  quantity_out  flag
0       A       z420            1     IN       12125        100.0           NaN     0
1       A       z420            1    OUT    A-z512-2          NaN         100.0     0
2       A       z512            2     IN    A-z512-2        100.0           NaN     0
3       A       z512            2    OUT    A-z600-3          NaN         120.0     0
4       A       z600            3     IN    A-z600-2          NaN         400.0     1
5       A       z600            3     IN    A-z600-3        120.0         200.0     1 # <- only valid flag (non-na quantity_in)
6       A       z600            3     IN       14551          NaN         -20.0     0
7       A       z600            3    OUT           A          NaN         100.0     0
```

Here's one way you may implement `calculate_demand_raw` without using `.apply` + `.loc` lookups.

Generally the you want to `.merge` in cases like this so you have all the data "side-by-side" which allows you to then work in a "vectorized manner".

```
flags = df[df['flag'] == 1].dropna(subset='quantity_in')

df_m = df.merge(flags, on=['item_id', 'process_No.'], how='left', suffixes=('', '_y'))

df_m.loc[ 
   (df_m['flag'] == 1) | (df_m['IN/OUT'] == 'OUT'), 
   df.columns.difference(['item_id', 'process_No.']) + '_y' 
] = float('nan')

rows = df_m['process_id_y'].notna()
df_m.loc[rows, 'quantity_out'] *= df_m.loc[rows, 'quantity_in_y']

df_m.loc[df_m['flag'] == 1, 'flag'] = 0
df_m.loc[rows, 'flag'] = 1
```

A breakdown of the steps:

Find all flag rows.

```
flags = df[df['flag'] == 1].dropna(subset='quantity_in')
```

The `.dropna()` is to emulate the `if np.isnan(row['quantity_out'])` line in your code.

```
  item_id process_id  process_No. IN/OUT material_id  quantity_in  quantity_out  flag
5       A       z600            3     IN    A-z600-3        120.0         200.0     1
```

left-merge with flags:

```
df_m = df.merge(flags, on=['item_id', 'process_No.'], how='left', suffixes=('', '_y'))
```

```
  item_id process_id  process_No. IN/OUT material_id  quantity_in  quantity_out  flag process_id_y IN/OUT_y material_id_y  quantity_in_y  quantity_out_y  flag_y
0       A       z420            1     IN       12125        100.0           NaN     0          NaN      NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN     NaN
1       A       z420            1    OUT    A-z512-2          NaN         100.0     0          NaN      NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN     NaN
2       A       z512            2     IN    A-z512-2        100.0           NaN     0          NaN      NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN     NaN
3       A       z512            2    OUT    A-z600-3          NaN         120.0     0          NaN      NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN     NaN
4       A       z600            3     IN    A-z600-2          NaN         400.0     1         z600       IN      A-z600-3          120.0           200.0     1.0
5       A       z600            3     IN    A-z600-3        120.0         200.0     1         z600       IN      A-z600-3          120.0           200.0     1.0
6       A       z600            3     IN       14551          NaN         -20.0     0         z600       IN      A-z600-3          120.0           200.0     1.0
7       A       z600            3    OUT           A          NaN         100.0     0         z600       IN      A-z600-3          120.0           200.0     1.0
```

You want to discard `OUT` rows, it's unclear if you want to compare the flag rows with themselves so I've discarded them here.

You can reset the `_y` columns on the rows you want to discard back to `NaN`

```
df_m.loc[ 
   (df_m['flag'] == 1) | (df_m['IN/OUT'] == 'OUT'), 
   df.columns.difference(['item_id', 'process_No.']) + '_y' 
] = float('nan')
```

```
  item_id process_id  process_No. IN/OUT material_id  quantity_in  quantity_out  flag process_id_y IN/OUT_y material_id_y  quantity_in_y  quantity_out_y  flag_y
0       A       z420            1     IN       12125        100.0           NaN     0          NaN      NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN     NaN
1       A       z420            1    OUT    A-z512-2          NaN         100.0     0          NaN      NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN     NaN
2       A       z512            2     IN    A-z512-2        100.0           NaN     0          NaN      NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN     NaN
3       A       z512            2    OUT    A-z600-3          NaN         120.0     0          NaN      NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN     NaN
4       A       z600            3     IN    A-z600-2          NaN         400.0     1          NaN      NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN     NaN
5       A       z600            3     IN    A-z600-3        120.0         200.0     1          NaN      NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN     NaN
6       A       z600            3     IN       14551          NaN         -20.0     0         z600       IN      A-z600-3          120.0           200.0     1.0
7       A       z600            3    OUT           A          NaN         100.0     0          NaN      NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN     NaN
```

You can then perform your calculations on the rows with nonna `_y` values:

```
rows = df_m['process_id_y'].notna()
df_m.loc[rows, 'quantity_out'] *= df_m.loc[rows, 'quantity_in_y']
```

```
  item_id process_id  process_No. IN/OUT material_id  quantity_in  quantity_out  flag process_id_y IN/OUT_y material_id_y  quantity_in_y  quantity_out_y  flag_y
0       A       z420            1     IN       12125        100.0           NaN     0          NaN      NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN     NaN
1       A       z420            1    OUT    A-z512-2          NaN         100.0     0          NaN      NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN     NaN
2       A       z512            2     IN    A-z512-2        100.0           NaN     0          NaN      NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN     NaN
3       A       z512            2    OUT    A-z600-3          NaN         120.0     0          NaN      NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN     NaN
4       A       z600            3     IN    A-z600-2          NaN         400.0     1          NaN      NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN     NaN
5       A       z600            3     IN    A-z600-3        120.0         200.0     1          NaN      NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN     NaN
6       A       z600            3     IN       14551          NaN       -2400.0     0         z600       IN      A-z600-3          120.0           200.0     1.0
7       A       z600            3    OUT           A          NaN         100.0     0          NaN      NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN     NaN
```

Toggle the flag values:

```
df_m.loc[df_m['flag'] == 1, 'flag'] = 0
df_m.loc[rows, 'flag'] = 1
```

```
  item_id process_id  process_No. IN/OUT material_id  quantity_in  quantity_out  flag process_id_y IN/OUT_y material_id_y  quantity_in_y  quantity_out_y  flag_y
0       A       z420            1     IN       12125        100.0           NaN     0          NaN      NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN     NaN
1       A       z420            1    OUT    A-z512-2          NaN         100.0     0          NaN      NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN     NaN
2       A       z512            2     IN    A-z512-2        100.0           NaN     0          NaN      NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN     NaN
3       A       z512            2    OUT    A-z600-3          NaN         120.0     0          NaN      NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN     NaN
4       A       z600            3     IN    A-z600-2          NaN         400.0     0          NaN      NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN     NaN
5       A       z600            3     IN    A-z600-3        120.0         200.0     0          NaN      NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN     NaN
6       A       z600            3     IN       14551          NaN       -2400.0     1         z600       IN      A-z600-3          120.0           200.0     1.0
7       A       z600            3    OUT           A          NaN         100.0     0          NaN      NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN     NaN
```

Comment: thx for help,but could u tell me what is your pandas version? Because when I do the same code as                                                                                                                       "df_m.loc[ 
     (df_m['flag'] == 1) | (df_m['IN/OUT'] == 'OUT'), 
      df.columns.difference(['item_id', 'process_No.']) + '_y' 
] = float('nan')"                                                                                                                                I find my table added other new columns as "col name_y_y".Whats wrong

Comment: and colud I use this way during a recursion func? Is it right that every time I should merge a new table on df, and delete it in the end ?

Comment: forget the first question cause I use"df.columns.difference(df.columns)" instead of it

Comment: That was just instead of typing out the `_y` column names manually. What kind of recursive function do you have? Perhaps you can show an example.

Comment: The purpose of the function is to calculate the demand of the product on all components, so it needs to be recursive from the finished product all the way to the non-divisible raw material with this operation. As an example, product A in the table needs to be calculated all the way to find the demand of 12125. And at the end of each round of calculation I also need to subtract the inventory and then aggregate all the requirements of the same category before starting the next round

Comment: Thx again for help.Now my func only need 0.15s to process same example.U a my Clark Kent man.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. You should be able to use a similar technique with the `fill_demand` function too.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why the datatable I edit carefully in edit mode become such a shit lol.To compensate for this, I've included a screenshot of the table and properties from the preview in this reply
[image]

Comment: Can confirm the markdown table displayed properly for me in the preview editor, looks like a "bug"? The issue was the lack of a newline before the `attr: processs_id : Process id used` string.