# How to find values that can be found in other columns in polars quickly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-polars

I started learning polars because the performance of pandas was not adequate for my task, but before I started I wanted to know if it could meet my requirements.

Now I have a dataframe like this

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| v1 | v3 | x |
| v2 | v1 | y |

And I want to find those values in columnA, which could be find in columnB, like v1 in table, and then modify the value of other columns of the same row.

Suppose the size range of my data set is like (3e+5， 20) to (10e+5, 20)，and I need to perform this search operation on two of the columns (like `if colA.value == colB.value` in a database operation), which may be repeated ten to thirty times in func.

In pandas I learned a solution by pandas.merge:
[speed up my function about build bill of materials with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76478616/speed-up-my-function-about-build-bill-of-materials-with-pandas).

And it takes about 0.5s each time searching two columns in my computer. I want to know could polars performs faster than pandas in this operation? If it could, how to do it?

Thx for any help and suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Benchmarking this polars statement

```py
df.select(pl.col('a').filter(pl.col('a').is_in(pl.col('b'))))
```

On the sample df

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
  'a' : np.random.randint(1, 1_000_000_000, size=300_000),
  'b' : np.random.randint(1, 1_000_000_000, size=300_000)
})
```

I get an average of 9-10ms per run.

Comment: thx and， what if the ColA and ColB are in different df ? how should I code?

Comment: You can use [`with_context`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.with_context.html#polars.LazyFrame.with_context) but otherwise they will need to be in the same df

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have

```
df1 = pl.DataFrame({
    'a' : np.random.randint(1, int(1e6), size=int(1e6)),
    'b' : np.random.randint(1, int(1e6), size=int(1e6))
}).with_columns(
    (pl.lit("v")+pl.col(x).cast(pl.Utf8())).alias(x) for x in ['a','b']
)

df2 = pl.DataFrame({
    'c' : np.random.randint(1, int(1e6), size=int(1e6)),
    'd' : np.random.randint(1, int(1e6), size=int(1e6))
}).with_columns(
    (pl.lit("v")+pl.col(x).cast(pl.Utf8())).alias(x) for x in ['c','d']
)
```

If you want to know for each row of df1 where `a` is in `c` of df2 then you could do:

```
df1.with_columns(
    structcol=pl.when(pl.col('a').is_in(df2.get_column('c')))
        .then(pl.struct(
            b=pl.lit("here's one"),
            f=pl.lit("i'm redundant")
        ))
        .otherwise(pl.struct(
            b=pl.col('b'),
            f=pl.lit("also redundant")
        ))
    ).drop('b').unnest('structcol')
```

You mentioned that you want to change *some* columns so this uses a `struct` as the new column so that you can output multiple columns from a single `when`/`then`. A struct is like a DataFrame or a dict inside a column. The caveat here is that in both the `then` and the `otherwise` the struct needs to have the same fields. In other words you couldn't have the `then` assign `b` and `f` while the `otherwise` only assigns the `b`. Another caveat is that `unnest` will throw an error if any of the columns in the `struct` conflicts with an existing column so that's why we drop the `b` before the unnest.

You could also do this as a `join` which is analogous to `merge`

```
df1.join(df2, left_on='a', right_on='c')
```

This will only return the rows where there's a match and it brings the `d` column too. If you want all the rows from df1, you can add the `how='left'`. It will omit the `right_on` column since it's essentially a duplicate of the `left_on` column at this point. You can chain on another `with_columns` like this...

```
(
    df1
        .join(df2, 
              left_on='a', right_on='c', how='left')
        .with_columns(
            structcol=pl.when(pl.col('d').is_not_null())
                .then(pl.struct(
                    b=pl.lit("here's one"),
                    f=pl.lit("i'm redundant")
                ))
                .otherwise(pl.struct(
                    b=pl.col('b'),
                    f=pl.lit("also redundant")
                ))
        )
    .drop('b')
    .unnest('structcol')
)
```

In this case I changed the `when` clause to whether or not `d` is null instead of having it perform `is_in` again.

Comment: thx and how should I code if I want to modify values in df1's Col C if df1's Col A 's value are in df2's Col B?